# Counting the number of $GET name value pairs with the same name

Tags: php, get

With a a form checklist there will obviously often be multiple checked items with the same 'names' and different values checked.

If i want to write a php function which counts the number of checkboxes with a certain name that are checked (in this case with the generic name checkboxname) how do i do this.

Currently the short php code i wrote counts if there is one $GET with checkboxname as the name or tells me if there are 0. However it does not count above 1. Why is this?

Currently i was trying to use `numberofcheckboxes.php?checkboxname=firstvalue&checkboxname=secondvalue` as url to call the file

numberofcheckboxes.php:

```
function checknumber(){
$b;
$numberoftypes= count($_GET["checkboxname"]);
echo $numberoftypes;
if ($numberoftypes > 1) {$b = 'more than one were checked';}
echo $b;}  

checknumber();
```

Comment: you probably forgot to name your checkboxes with `[]`, so PHP won't create an array for you - only the **LAST** checkbox in the html will get submitted under that name. `var_dump($_GET)` will confirm that - if you didn't use `[], then the checkbox field will show as a normal string, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as Marc B has suggested.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[]" value="2" />
```

Adding the square brackets converts your GET/POST variable into an array.

If both checkboxes were checked you would get

```
$_GET['checkboxname'] == array(1, 2);
```

You can also use multi-dimensional array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[group1][]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[group1][]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[group2][]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[group2][]" value="4" />
```

Would be

```
$_GET['checkboxname'] == array('group1' => array(1, 2), 'group2' => array(3, 4));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It was hard to decide which one to vote as the answer but since yours included extra information that could be helpfull about multi dimensional arrays i chose it.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't use `[]` in the name:

```
numberofcheckboxes.php?checkboxname=firstvalue&checkboxname=secondvalue
                                   ^-----------------------^
```

Without `[]` in the name, PHP assumes each field will be a SINGLE value, and treats is a such. That means the LAST checkboxname in the URL is the value that takes effect.

You need:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[]" ... />
                                         ^^---
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply :)